# Можно ли как-то на jquery сначала отключить все обработчики, а затем включить?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно ли как-то сначала отключить все обработчики к событию 'click' у элементов внутри некоторого блока, а потом зарегистрировать(включить) их обратно без явного их перечисления в .on()?

Т.е. внутри некоторого блока есть N элементов, у каждого из которых на клике висят некие обработчики, их нужно отключить при условии А, а затем вернуть обратно при условии В, но так, чтобы не перечислять их явно.

Comment: Вынесите условие в переменную и проверяйте её внутри обработчиков.

Answer (score 0):

Можно придумать декоратор, который будет заниматься контролем выполнения:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const control = document.getElementById('control');

// функция вернет функцию, которая будет проверять
// если значение canInvoke = false, то функция
// которую передали не будет вызвана
// canInvoke может не быть св-вом shouldFuncInvoke
// главное обеспечить доступ к ее значению
const shouldFuncInvoke = (fn) => (...args) => {
  if(!shouldFuncInvoke.canInvoke) return;
  
  return fn(...args);
}

control.onchange = ({target}) => {
  shouldFuncInvoke.canInvoke = target.checked;
}

// используем
button.onclick = shouldFuncInvoke(() =>
  alert('shouldFuncInvoke.canInvoke == true'));
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='control'>
<label for='control'>Включить</label>
<hr />
<button id='button'>Кнопка</button>
```